# How do I dynamically change the source of my iFrame within xPages?

Tags: xpages

Good day, I have tried numerous alternatives to dynamically change the source of my iFrame to a specific variable. However, I am falling short please assist.

Comment: Please be more specific and include code that shows what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an iframe using  `<xp:panel tagName="Iframe">`
2. Then use the all properties pane and add an attr and set the name to src and make the value computed